# iOS new view not appearing and/or old view not disappering

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

i have two View Controllers in my project, the first one is for *Sign Up* view and the second one is for *Sign In* view. In the first view i have a sign in button which has a segue to the second *Sign In* view (i.e. if you've an account pass to *Sign In* view, please see attached image).

[image: Views]

Unfortunately, when i clicked *sign in* button in *Sign Up* view the second view(*Sign In* view) not opening.

I'm sure `prepareForSegue` is called and the button touch is certainly processed(`IBAction` for the button is called). Also `ViewDidLoad` of the view supposed to open is called, as you may guess `ViewDidAppear` of the same view is not called.

In a nutshell, what happens is button and segue is working and the second view is loading but it does not appear and the first view does not disappear. It happens all of a sudden(i.e. it was working properly before), i do not know what did happen or what i did mistakenly. If anybody can help me, it would be a great relief.

*I know, in this case IBAction and prepareForSegue are not necessarily to be used, these were used just to make sure that the button and the segue are working properly.

Comment: this segue is directly added on button?

Comment: Yes, it is, as you can observe in the image. It is from highlighted button (little sign in button) to View Controller of the second view(the view with the "Sign In" title).

Comment: if you added segue, then why you need an IBAction for that button, commented the code within action method and see

Comment: I do not need IBAction, it is just to see whether button is working. The exact problem here is old view not disappearing or the new view not appearing. I've mentioned IBAction and prepareForSegue not because they are needed, to emphasize button and segue is ok.

Comment: could you post your viewDidLoad's code..maybe something in that preventing it from completing..only if viewDidLoad completes will viewWillAppear get called

Comment: Ok, i'll double check and i'll try with an empty viewDidLoad, if i see necessity, i will share, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Do let us know what worked...

Comment: @Meharoof Najeeb, i'd really appreciate your comment, i empty viewDidLoad and it is working. Now i have to handle, what is problematic in viewDidLoad lines and have to fix them, etc. but you really save my day(i've also spent my yesterday :/ ).